# docker-php environment with docker-compose.yml and links error

Tags: php, docker

I am trying to setup a development environment for upgrading old php applications with docker. I've tried to create a docker-compose.yml file with the following content:

```
version: "3"
services:

  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=dev
      - MYSQL_USER=dev
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=dev
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=todo
    volumes:
      - ./storage/mysql:/var/lib/mysql

  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - ./../src:/var/www
      - ./site.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/site.conf
    links:
      - php

  php:
    image: tommylau/php-5.2
    volumes:
      - ./../src:/var/www
    depends_on:
      - mysql
```

There may be additional issues within my yml file but at first i'm facint two problems here:

1) what about links?

when using

```
$ docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml phpdev
```

i'm getting the following output saying the links option is unssupported and i don't see why

```
Ignoring unsupported options: links

Creating network phpdev_default
Creating service phpdev_nginx
Creating service phpdev_php
Creating service phpdev_mysql
```

2) nothing on localhost:8080

any hints on solving my two problems?

Comment: You do not need to add link between containers in same stack. Take a look at [Using service and container names as hostnames](https://docs.docker.com/docker-cloud/apps/service-links/#using-service-and-container-names-as-hostnames): > A container can always discover other containers on the same stack using just the container name as hostname. This includes containers of the same service. Similarly, a container can always discover other services on the same stack using the service name.


And could you dump the output of `docker logs phpdev_nginx`?

Comment: i see - and searching for more info from nginx (there is no container phpdev_nginx so docker logs did not return anything) if used docker service ps phpdev_nginx and got: "No such image: nginx:latest" - something to work with. thx for pointing me in a direction